# Reorder divs after resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my divs to act as so, whilst able to use transitions for the motion (example if div2 is clicked):

**from**

[div1][div2]

[div3][div4]

-

**to**

[---div2----]

[div1][div3]

[div4]

The problem so far is apparent in the codepen i've attached.

What would be the best way to make this happen with my divs:

Html

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="cell1" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
 <div id="cell2" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
 <div id="cell3" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
 <div id="cell4" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
 <div id="cell5" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
 <div id="cell6" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.container{
width:300px;
}
.cell{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:solid black 1px;
display:inline-block;
transition:background-color 1s;
}
.cell:hover{
background-color: blue;
}
.click {
background-color: green;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var clickFunction = function(elem){

        if(elem.classList.contains("click")){
            elem.classList.remove("click")
        }
        else{
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

            for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){

            if(elements[i].classList.contains("click")){
                elements[i].classList.remove("click");

            }
            }
            elem.classList.add("click");
        }
    }
```

**codepen**

[So far](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGwyqp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code below. I used flex.

```js
var clickFunction = function(elem){

        if(elem.classList.contains("click")){
            elem.classList.remove("click")
        }
        else{
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

            for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){

            if(elements[i].classList.contains("click")){
                elements[i].classList.remove("click");

            }
            }
            elem.classList.add("click");
        }
    }
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid black 1px;
  display:inline-block;
  transition:background-color 1s;
  order: 2;
  
}
.cell:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}
.click {
  background-color: green;
  width:200px;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="cell" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300?text=Cell 1" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
  <img class="cell" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300?text=Cell 2" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
  <img class="cell" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300?text=Cell 3" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
  <img class="cell" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300?text=Cell 4" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect! such an elegant solution! i was going to be faffing with loads of javascript. much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Id appreciate if you marked my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You are already using Javascript, so you might as well do the reordering with it. There are probably ways to achieve this with pure HTML / CSS3. (See @izulito's faster answer :)

```js
var clickFunction = function(elem) {
  if (elem.classList.contains("click")) {
    elem.classList.remove("click");
    var pos = parseInt(elem.getAttribute("data-num"));
    var nodeAfter = document.querySelector("cell[data-num='" + (pos + 1) + "]'");
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, nodeAfter);
  } else {
    var oldSelection = document.querySelector(".cell.click");
    if (oldSelection) {
      oldSelection.classList.remove("click");
    }
    elem.classList.add("click");
    var nodeAfter = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, nodeAfter);
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.cell {
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  width: 100px;
}
.cell:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.click {
  background-color: green;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div data-num="1" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div><div data-num="2" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div><div data-num="3" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div><div data-num="4" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div><div data-num="5" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div><div data-num="6" class="cell" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></div></div>
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm probably going to use @izulito's answer as my knowledge is still pretty basic. But your response gives me something to study to help me learn, so thanks for that!